# How to collect tuple values in if statement?

Tags: python, opencv, if-statement, image-processing, contour

I have a code which consists of `if` statement in `for` loop as below,

```
for i in range(len(contours)):

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    mask[y:y+w, x:x+w] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, i, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

    if r > 0.5 and w > 8 and h > 8:
        cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(rgb, (x+w/2,y+h/2), 3, (180, 25, 20), -1)
        start_target_states = x+w/2 , y+h/2
        print "start_target_states: %s" % (start_target_states,)
```

when running this code, it results as below;

```
start_target_states: (704, 463)
start_target_states: (83, 15)
```

However, `start_target_states` variable must be named as `start_state` for the first result, afterwards, it must be named as `target_state` for the second result. For example;

```
target_state: (704, 463)
start_state: (83, 15)
```

Moreover, I want to assign these two tuples to variable name. So that I can use them later.I mean,

```
TargetState = target_state
StartState = start_state
```

I have tried to modify if statement to reach my purpose, unfortunately I could not get succeed. How can I do what I want?

Comment: do you always get only two values printed in the `if` condition?

Comment: Edited: It may change due to the image. But for now, yes I am getting only two values. Also, I am getting more values when I use `print` function out of the `if` condition. All in all, I need two values ,as above, that must be assigned as variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to access them later, you can just add them to a list.

```
states = []
for i in range(len(contours)):

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    mask[y:y+w, x:x+w] = 0
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, i, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

    if r > 0.5 and w > 8 and h > 8:
        cv2.rectangle(rgb, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(rgb, (x+w/2,y+h/2), 3, (180, 25, 20), -1)
        start_target_states = x+w/2 , y+h/2
        states.append(start_target_states)
        print "start_target_states: %s" % (start_target_states,)
```

Since you have them in a list you can still access them because you aren't overriding them each time.

```
target_state = states[0]
start_state = states[1]
```

or more generally, if you want to capture the first and last:

```
target_state = states[0]
start_state = states[-1]
```

Also, it's not what you were asking about, but it is better practice to use `enumerate` for this kind of loop.

```
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
```

and then instead of using `counters[i]` you can just use `contour`.